# NPM: Peer dependency of react native

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I'm trying to create my first react native application on my MacBook:

```
$ npm install -g react-native-cli
```

In my package.json there is

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "~15.4.0-rc.4",
    "react-native": "0.41.0",
    "react-native-image-carousel": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.25.7",
    "react-native-local-mongodb": "^1.8.2"
  }
}
```

With `npm install` I got the message

```
npm WARN react-native-image-carousel@0.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@^0.40.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-swipeable-views-native@0.10.5 requires a peer of react-native@^0.39.0 but none was installed.
```

What do I have to do?